# Spice Server Codec problem

Tags: qemu, gstreamer, spice

I compiled(make) spice server source with option '--enable-gstreamer=0.10.36'.

But As a result of debugging, I've found that 'default_video_codecs' still shows 'spice: mjpeg'.

I want to know what action is needed to get it set to 'gstreamer: h264'.